# Getting JBoss Seam to work with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, seam, tomcat6

I have been trying to get to run a simple example project with JBoss Seam in Eclipse 3.5.
So far unsuccessfully.

What i did:

- I set up a MySQL server that i can connect to using eclipse's data tools.
- I installed Tomcat 6.0 and set it up as a server in eclipse
- I installed the "JBossAS Tools" v2.2.0 plugin
- I created a new Seam Project using the plugin.

But i keep getting

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: HelloWorldSeamProjektDatasource not bound
```

I have been reading a lot of forums and playing around with the web.xml, server.xml, context.xml and HelloWorldSeamProjekt-ds.xml.

My guess is that the JNDI setup of my database resource is broken. I tried a bunch of different approaches like a global resource, different names (comp/env/)
but nothing worked.

All the tutorials i found use different (and mostly outdated) combinations of Seam, Tomcat and Eclipse.

I'm getting frustrated.

Can someone please point me to a simple setup to get me started?

Comment: Can you post your HelloWorldSeamProjekt-ds.xml? Also are there any signs of thrown exceptions the server log, when trying to initialize the datasource (before the NameNotFoundExceptions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should do instead is use seam-gen to generate your eclipse project. This will do it right.

You can see how you can get started using seam-gen [here](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.1.CR1/reference/en-US/html/gettingstarted.html)

Comment: Good, Shervin (+1) Just as additional comment, here goes output generated by seam-gen: **Eclipse Users: Add the project into Eclipse using File > New > Project and select General > Project (not Java Project)**

Comment: That helped somewhat as i at least got the created project to run in JBoss. What didn't help though is that seam-gen and the Seam Tools use completely different structures, files and deployment methods. And instead of reducing the number of required xml files, Seam is so far doubling it.

Comment: There are lots of the xml files and other files you can delete. They are mainly there to support other environments and files that are needed